# Git and exclude subfolder

Tags: git

My repo has following structure:

```
- Data
-- Audio
-- Video
```

I want to include Audio but exclude Video. I wrote in info/exclude

```
Data/Video
```

but this didn't work. The following didn't work either:

```
Data/
!Data/Audio
```

Strangely, but this works:

```
Data/
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: have you tried `Data/Video/*` ?

Comment: yes, result is the same

Comment: What do you mean by "this didn't work"? How did you determine it didn't work? You can't ignore files which are already tracked, is it possible that this is the case with Video?

Comment: I'm using Git with Xcode. When exclude='Data/Video/' Xcode offers all files to commit including files in Video. But when exclude='Data/' then files from Audio and Video are not present in the commit list

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
Data/Video/
```

The trailing `/` is important when ignoring a folder.

Comment: All these combinations don't work: 'Data/Video', 'Data/Video/', Data/Video/*', 'Data/Video/somefile.m4v'

Comment: @Vas test it in command line: do a git status and see if those Video files are still listed

Comment: @Vas also, what version of XCode are you using, with what version of git?